# golang javascript object equivalent

Tags: javascript, go

In Javascript, we can create objects like this:

```
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
```

So if we want to print the car's model, then we do this in the console:

```
console.log(car.model);
```

or

```
console.log(car['model']);
```

Then, we will get:

```
"500"
```

Does Golang have something similar to Javascript Objects? Or how can I approach to this solution?

Comment: I think you’re looking for [structs](https://gobyexample.com/structs).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Golang is a statically typed language, so generally you would define the data type ahead of time, specifying field types and such to allow the compiler to check type mismatches for you.

Or you can use a `map` as long as all the values stored in there are of the same type:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type car struct {
    Type  string
    Model string
    Color string
}

func main() {
    c1 := car{
        Type:  "Fiat",
        Model: "500",
        Color: "white",
    }
    fmt.Println(c1.Model)

    c2 := map[string]string{
        "Type":  "Fiat",
        "Model": "500",
        "Color": "white",
    }
    fmt.Printl(c2["Model"])
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Map is a good option since I can add more properties like js
car["wheels"] = 4
fmt.Println(car["wheels"])
->4
I like it.